# NancyFx - Find the server over a local network

Tags: c#, sql-server, nancy, .net-standard-2.0

**Scenario:** I have a small POS system running in a brick-and-mortar store. The software is running in Windows machines with SQL Server 2008 - 2012 (it varies). There are Android tablets that need to connect to the server in someway to get the data inside SQL Server.

My plan right now is to create some REST Web services using NancyFx and host them as a Windows Service inside the Windows machines. Then the Android tablets will need to connect to the server via HTTP in order to consume the REST API.

I have a problem (perhaps more than one): the network in the brick-and-mortar store is not that reliable and the Wi-Fi signal might decrease for whatever reason.

**Question:** Is there a way to automatically find the IP or machine name of the server (the one with the REST API) even if these properties change for some reason (unknown network issues or so)?

Yes, the server and the tablets are going to be on the same local network.

Comment: why aren't you using fix ip for the server ? or DNS name to access the server

Answer (score 0):

it's more of a network problem than programming issue. you must have a DHCP server installed in your LAN. use that to assign an IP to the server with a fixed lease. that way you fix the address of server. clients should preferably connect to that server using its name. since it's a Windows network, name would resolve to the ip address.

that is the simplest solution i can think of